# Gson toJson() method problem with HashMap<String,Object>

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, gson

I have used Gson to serialize Map<String,Object> to json, but I encountered some problems, can you tell me why this happens?

Code:

```
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        this.put("test",1);
    }};
    HashMap<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("test",1);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map));
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map2));
```

Output:

```
null 
{"test":1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have declared it, `map` is not a HashMap, but an anonymous class. Gson is not designed to handle anonymous and inner classes.

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/298), which asks about serialization of anonymous class, but it's closed, so probably there are no plans to add support for this. As you can see in the discussion, possible workaround is providing the type.

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType()));
```

Another [related discussion](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2059).

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the code, you will see that `map.getClass()` will not return a "HashMap" as you might expect, but an anonymous class (if you run the code in a class named *Main*, then the `map.getClass()` will be something like *Main$1*).

`map2.getClass()` will return *HashMap* as expected.

If you check *Gson method toJson* Javadocs:

> This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json
> representation. This method should be used when the specified object
> is not a generic type. This method uses Object.getClass() to get the
> type for the specified object, but the getClass() loses the generic
> type information because of the Type Erasure feature of Java. Note
> that this method works fine if the any of the object fields are of
> generic type, just the object itself should not be of a generic type.
> If the object is of generic type, use toJson(Object, Type) instead. If
> you want to write out the object to a Writer, use toJson(Object,
> Appendable) instead.

To solve your "problem" you must specify `map` type.

Example:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
  this.put("test",1);
}};
Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("test",1);

final Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
}.getType();

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map, type));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map2));
```

**Reference**: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html